# What is the use of requireJS in Angular6/5?

Tags: angular6, requirejs

What is the basic usage of using requireJS with Angular5/6. 
How the usage of requireJS can optimize Angular applications?

Comment: I don't think the two are even outright compatible since you have to compile Angular apps with a build tool.  It would be even more effort with almost no benefit to use the two together.  Why do you think you need to?

Answer (score 0):

RequireJS is quiet old system. You should not use it for new projects. Better use Webpack or something similar :)